# C# float data type

Tags: c#, .net

Why is the following a wrong declaration:

```
float realNumber = 12.5;
```

Why do I need to put `f` at the end like this:

```
float realNumber = 12.5f;
```

What is the purpose of declaring it a `float` datatype if the default is `double`? Sorry, but I am just starting to learn C# through [this](http://www.introprogramming.info/english-intro-csharp-book/read-online/chapter-2-primitive-types-and-variables/) website and I am a beginner. Thanks!

Comment: I understand what they were saying in the other answer. But unless the answer to my question is "because that is how C# was designed" it doesn't answer what the purpose of the float data type is if you still have to put an `f` at the end.

Comment: `12.5` literal is of type `double`. There is no implicit conversion from `double` to `float` (because that conversion is not loseless). For that reason you cannot assign value of type `double` to variable of type `float`.

Comment: Because that's how C# was designed. They had to pick _a_ default data type for floating-point values.

Comment: @CodeCaster The way you said it made it click for me now. They have two data types for the same kind of real number (only one has more decimals). Evk's implicit conversion comment makes sense now, too. Thanks!